# Multiple triggers in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is described in a Jenkinsfile as a declarative pipeline.
I need this pipeline to be triggered both by a cron and by a custom Jenkins trigger, comming from a plug-in.
I tried to define it as follow:

```
pipeline {
  ...
  triggers {
    myCustomTrigger()
    cron('0 21 * * *')
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't even know if it is supposed to work. The custom trigger is never taken into account. Only the cron seems to work in that configuration.
Does anyone have any idea how should I proceed for my pipeline to be run either on the cron or custom trigger?

Many thanks!

Comment: Jenkins only [supports triggers](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) of type: `[ cron, pollSCM, upstream ]`.